# Quick Sort Algorithm using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I took  the first element as starting and pivot value.
Incrementing start position when pivot is less than end value.
Decrementing end position when pivot is greater than end value.
Also, swapping starting and ending position when  each pass completes.
If starting position cross the end position then I'm swapping pivot and end elements.

```
def partition(arr, lb, ub):
  pivot = arr[lb]  
  start = lb
  print('start', start)
  end = ub
  print('end', end)
  while start <= end:

    while arr[start] <= pivot:
          start += 1
    while arr[end] >= pivot:
          end -= 1
    if start <= end:
      arr[start], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[start]
    else:
      arr[end], arr[lb] = arr[lb], arr[end]
    return end 

def quickSort(arr, lb, ub): 
    if lb >= ub:
      return 0
    loc = partition(arr, lb, ub)
    quickSort(arr, lb, loc-1) 
    quickSort(arr, loc+1, ub) 

arr = [10, 4, 7, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1, 5, 2] 

n = len(arr)
print(n)
quickSort(arr, 0, len(arr) -1) 
print ("Sorted array is:") 
for i in range(n): 
    print("%d" % arr[i])
```

I am getting the following error:
    IndexError

```
---> quickSort(arr, 0, len(arr) -1)

Error in partition(arr, lb, ub)

---> while arr[start] <= pivot:


IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please tell whats wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1):

This is the direct cause of the error:

```
    while arr[start] <= pivot:
          start += 1
    while arr[end] >= pivot:
          end -= 1
```

You don't check whether `start` isn't larger than `ub` (and whether `end` isn't smaller than `lb`). This is what you should do:

```
        while start < ub and arr[start] <= pivot:
            start += 1
        while end > lb and arr[end] >= pivot:
            end -= 1
```

However, there's another thing that is wrong:

```
    while start <= end:
```

should be

```
    while start < end:
```

because for the weak inequality the loop never ends - it reaches the state of `start == end` and loops there endlessly. The inequality here:

```
       if start <= end:
```

also should be a strong one, otherwise for `start == end` you're swapping `arr[end]` with `arr[start]` (ie. itself) instead of `arr[lb]` (ie. the pivot).

And finally, formatting of your code posted here was botched, so I took the liberty of fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still don't have a solution yet, but here is a revised partition function.

```
def partition(arr, lb, ub):
  pivot = arr[lb]
  start = lb + 1
  print('start', start)
  end = ub
  print('end', end)
  while start <= end:
    while start <= end and arr[start] <= pivot:
      start += 1
    while end >= start and arr[end] > pivot:
      end -= 1
    if start < end:
      arr[start], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[start]
  if start >= end:
    start -= 1
  arr[start], arr[lb] = arr[lb], arr[start]
  return start
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check whether `start` does not increments more than the `end` such as following,

```
while arr[start] <= pivot:
    if start<end:
          start += 1
```

Comment: This won't work, since you access `arr[start]` before checking if `start` isn't too large.